# Java is trying to do if statement that is not true

Tags: java, button, if-statement, jtextfield, void

I'm trying to do a program that if two `TextField`s are equal to a value something will happen and I have two `if` statements. When the first `if` statement happens the second `if` statement happens but the value I set in the code does not match. To explain better, here is the code:

```
private void LevelUp(){
        float level = (float) Double.parseDouble(lvl.getText());
        float expmn = (float) Double.parseDouble(ExpMin.getText());
                    if(level == 1  && expmn == 500){
                    lvl.setText("2");
                    ExpMin.setText("501");
                    ExpMax.setText("1000");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"" + "levevlup!" ,"Para Yok",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                    if(level == 2 && expmn == 1000); 
                        lvl.setText("3");
                        ExpMin.setText("1001");
                        ExpMax.setText("2500");

        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"" + "leveladssadaup" ,"Para Yok",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note the `;` after `if(level == 2 && expmn == 1000)`

Comment: `if(level == 2 && expmn == 1000);` looks suspicious.

Comment: This is one reason why you never leave out optional `{ }`.

Comment: This is why it's a good habit to get into to *always* uses braces with your if-then-else statements.

Comment: ...showing why you should use curly braces after `if` statements.

Comment: Use an editor that does syntax highlighting and indentation.

Comment: Thanks Jon the problem solved i just signed up minutes ago i didnt know the answer could come that fast :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not only you should erase the `;` after the if-statement where you look for level2, but if I look into your code correctly, you should close your if-statement where you look for level1 before asking for level2 and use else if for the level2.

Also go for curly braces after the level2 if:

```
    if(level == 1  && expmn == 500){
                lvl.setText("2");
                ExpMin.setText("501");
                ExpMax.setText("1000");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"" + "levevlup!" ,"Para Yok",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }// <-- close level1 here because you want to check for a new level afterwards
    else if(level == 2 && expmn == 1000){ //<-- here was your ;, which was wrong
                    lvl.setText("3");
                    ExpMin.setText("1001");
                    ExpMax.setText("2500");

    }
    else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"" + "leveladssadaup" ,"Para Yok",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `;` from

```
 if(level == 2 && expmn == 1000);
```

and add a `{`

```
 if(level == 2 && expmn == 1000) {
```

You also need to add a closing `}` to this `if` statement

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
private void LevelUp(){
    float level = (float) Double.parseDouble(lvl.getText());
    float expmn = (float) Double.parseDouble(ExpMin.getText());
    if(level == 1  && expmn == 500){
        lvl.setText("2");
        ExpMin.setText("501");
        ExpMax.setText("1000");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"" + "levevlup!" ,"Para Yok",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);


    }
    else{
    if(level == 2 && expmn == 1000)
    {
            lvl.setText("3");
            ExpMin.setText("1001");
            ExpMax.setText("2500");
    }
    else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"" + "leveladssadaup" ,"Para Yok",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
    }
}
```